# interfaceorientation remains same after removeFromSuperview and again addSubview

Tags: iphone, animation, uiinterfaceorientation, addsubview

I am switching between views using view animations, its works but I am having an issue with interface orientation.

I have two views on window.

1. authenticationViewCont
2. mainViewCont

Both have a button, when button clicked on `authenticationViewCont` I remove it and show `mainViewCont` and vice versa.

**Once I addSubview the `authenticationViewCont.view` and putting device in portrait mode then removed it by `removeFromSuperview` then I change device orientation to landscape in my hands then again addSubview the `authenticationViewCont`. It first displayed animating in portrait and changing orientation after animation.**

```
-(void)mainToAuthentication {
    CGRect originalFrame = authenticationViewCont.view.frame;
    CGRect modifiedFrame = originalFrame;
    modifiedFrame.origin.y = originalFrame.size.height;
    // made view out from screen
    authenticationViewCont.view.frame = modifiedFrame;
    // add sub view on top of other views
    [self.window addSubview:authenticationViewCont.view];
    // transiting view from bottom to center of screen
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
        animations:^{ authenticationViewCont.view.frame = originalFrame; }
        completion:^(BOOL finished){ mainViewCont.view removeFromSuperview; }];
}

-(void)authenticationToMain {
    CGRect originalFrame = mainViewCont.view.frame;
    CGRect modifiedFrame = originalFrame;
    modifiedFrame.origin.y = -originalFrame.size.height;
    // made view out from screen
    mainViewCont.view.frame = modifiedFrame;
    // add sub view on top of other views
    [self.window addSubview:mainViewCont.view];
    // transiting view from top to center of screen
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
        animations:^{ mainViewCont.view.frame = originalFrame; }
        completion:^(BOOL finished){ authenticationViewCont.view removeFromSuperview; }];
}
```

How can I make it to display in current interface orientation instead of old interface orientation in which it was `removeFromSuperview`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you are initialliy adding one viewController.view ontop of another then removing the old one.

The problem with window only expects one rootViewController.  So the window will only pass rotation events onto the first controller.  Meaning your second viewController will not get rotation events until the completionsBlock gets called.

The way I would get around this is to put this switching code inside of a rootViewController that is on the window.  Then whenever you do your switching you can pass in the current rotation of the rootviewController and have your authenticationViewController set itself up based on the orientation you pass it